# How to remove "warning:Cannot use a scalar value as an array"

Tags: php

here is my code:

```
$i = 0;
$list4 = array();
while($row_sent = $GLOBALS['db']->sql_fetchrow($res_sent))
{   
    $sql_sent2 = "SELECT * FROM ".$GLOBALS['table']['sent']." WHERE `sent_id` ='".$row_sent['sent_id']."'";
    //echo $sql_size2; exit;
    $res_sent2 = $GLOBALS['db']->sql_query($sql_sent2);
    $num = $GLOBALS['db']->sql_numrows($res_sent2);
    if($num > 0)
    {
        while($row_sent2 = $GLOBALS['db']->sql_fetchrow($res_sent2))
        {
             $list4[$i]['sent_id']             = $row_sent2['sent_id']; //this line shows error
             $list4[$i]['sent_name']           = $row_sent2['sent_name'];//this line shows error
             $list4[$i]['sent_qty']            = $row_sent['sent_qty'];//this line shows error
        }
    }
    else
    {
      $list4=0;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: i comment that three lines from where I get this warning

Comment: Also, `$list4` can be overwritten by the else statement which makes $list4 an integer, not an array.

Comment: @thetaiko still I got that warning

Comment: Don't attempt to use a scalar value as an array.

Comment: I did "return $list4[$i]; "                                         thanks now warning is removed but that sql query didn't return any result. how to solve this?

Comment: @tjm: @thetaiko: [No](http://codepad.org/8lDi27cE).

Comment: @Moumita: Instead of trying to hack through your problems one PHP warning/notice/error at a time, I think that you should take a step back and look at what your code is doing, line by line.

Comment: @Tomalak, yeah just saw the extra problem and deleted my answer. Edit. Oh wow *really* No! I didn't realise that, cool. Thanks.

Comment: BTW to all who are _not_ psychic, I'm going to assume that the OP is using [this DB abstraction](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Database_Abstraction_Layer#sql_fetchrow) layer, since (s)he couldn't be bothered to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

declare `$list4` as an array before your loop start.

```
$list4[] = array();
```

this may be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: then what will return? is it $list4[] or $list4

Comment: obviously **$list4**..but its work like multidimensional array. try this. thx.

Comment: Have you put this line inside first **while loop** or not ? if not then please put inside first **while loop** and then try again.